# Creating a file in a Windows Kernel driver using ZwCreateFile builds succesfully - Doesn't actually create a file

Tags: window, kernel

I'm trying to create a Windows Kernel Driver so that when I use "sc start <service_name>", it will create a .txt file. I have the code for you below.

NOTE: The code builds in VS2022 successfully. Also, "sc create" and "sc start <service_name>" work perfectly.

Can you tell me what is wrong with the code. All help is appreciated.

```
#include <ntddk.h>


VOID DriverUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);
NTSTATUS DispatchCreateClose(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp);

extern "C" NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT   DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = DispatchCreateClose;
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID DriverUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
}


NTSTATUS
DispatchCreateClose(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT   DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP  Irp)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpStack;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    UNICODE_STRING fileName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock;
    HANDLE fileHandle;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    irpStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    if (irpStack->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE)
    {

        
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&fileName, L"\\DosDevices\\C:\\example.txt");

        InitializeObjectAttributes(&objectAttributes, &fileName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

        status = ZwCreateFile(&fileHandle,
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            &objectAttributes,
            &ioStatusBlock,
            NULL,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            0,
            FILE_OVERWRITE_IF,
            FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
            NULL,
            0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            ZwClose(fileHandle);
            return status;
        }

        Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
        Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

        return status;
    }
    else {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Comment: In order to create a new file, this code needs to be modified and put inside of PsCreateSystemThread() function. You should also make sure that place to which you want to store "example.txt" exists. I created a C:\Temp file.